# WebRTC handle peerConnection error

Tags: webrtc

I was wondering if there is way to check when peerConnection fail to connect to the STUN server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, there's no direct way to do this.

However, if you pass in a STUN server and then don't get any STUN candidates during the gathering process (and your local candidates are nonroutable), that means the STUN server couldn't be contacted.